# Typescript interface conformance with firestore queries

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How do I work with Firebase and my own Typescript interfaces?

ie. I have a function here that I'm going to need the full `Payment` object, (not just the delta), so I get that via the [`DocumentReference`](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.8.x/DocumentReference) object.

```
function doSomethingWithPayment(payment: Payment) {
   console.log(payment.amount); 
}


exports.resolveStripeCharge = functions.firestore.document('/payments/{paymentId}')
    .onWrite((change : Change <DocumentSnapshot>) => {

        change.after.ref.get().then((doc: DocumentSnapshot )=> {
            const payment : Payment =   doc.data(); // tslint warning here. 
            doSomethingWithPayment(payment); 

        })


[ts]
Type 'DocumentData' is not assignable to type 'Payment'.
  Property 'amount' is missing in type 'DocumentData'.
const payment: Payment
```

I get that the returned object wont necessarily conform the interface - but in anycase -what should I do here - if I want to enforce typing?

Do I just use:

```
 const payment : Payment =   <Payment>doc.data();
```

Or is there a much nicer solution?

Comment: firestore is a dumpstorefire

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The solution you have is just typecasting the `doc.data()`. That is
>   not a solution, its a workaround. Because, by doing so you might face
>   run time errors.

So, what I would suggest is, just use :

`const payment = doc.data()`

In case of `const`, the typing will be automatically enforced.

**OR**

> You can write a function which converts the `DocumentData` type to the
>   `Payment` type. by adding the missing params.

Comment: I've updated my example to demonstrate why I want to enforce typing.

Comment: @dwjohnston even if you enforce typing by typecasting, the property `amount` don't exist and your function `doSomethingWithPayment` won't be able to print the value of `amount`.

Comment: @dwjohnston. you can write a function which converts the `DocumentData` type to the `Payment` type. by adding the missing params.

Answer (score 4):

Given that `doc.data()` [always returns](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-firestore/blob/55932b9fd9fd1cdf4adcc2c9ea332671f7cf446e/types/firestore.d.ts#L646) a `DocumentData`, which [is just](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-firestore/blob/55932b9fd9fd1cdf4adcc2c9ea332671f7cf446e/types/firestore.d.ts#L28) `{[field: string]: any}`, I don't think there's any better way to turn that into a `Payment` than casting.  You could write:

```
const data = doc.data();
const payment = {amount: doc.amount, /*and so on for the remaining members*/};
```

without a cast, but I don't think that's better in practical terms.  It would make more sense to me for `DocumentData` to be just `any` (like the return of `JSON.parse` to give one example); you could file an issue [on the project](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-firestore) to propose that.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this helps, but the way I think of it is that the type you have in your program and the types you send and recieve from Firestore are different types.

So, typescript has this 'Partial' feature that takes an interface and makes all of the fields optional. That way even if the object isn't complete, it will still conform and provide you with intellisense.

So, I do this : 
`export type dataUpdate<T> = Partial<T>;`

Then, I do : 
`const userPayload: dataUpdate<User> = snapshot/typecase as User`

Answer (score 0):

At least as of version 8 of the Javascript SDK (v9 is in open beta), Firestore now has a [**FirestoreDataConverter** interface](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v9/firestore_.firestoredataconverter) to specify types when adding or retrieving document data:

This allows the use of the [**withConverter()** method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v9/firestore_.query.md#querywithconverter_2) when performing a [Query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v9/firestore_.query), to ensure that the document data is modeled onto an object/class/interface and meets its type requirements.

<sub>1. Google broke the link for the [**FirestoreDataConverter** interface](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v9/firestore_.firestoredataconverter), but you can search GH `@google-cloud/firestore` src for "[`export interface FirestoreDataConverter`](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-firestore/search?q=%22export+interface+FirestoreDataConverter%22)"</sub>