# cloud functions typescript snapshot.val() type safety

Tags: typescript, firebase, types, casting, google-cloud-functions

```
functions.firestore.document('/foos/{fooId}').onUpdate(

(change: Change<DocumentSnapshot>, context: EventContext) => {
const snapshot = change.after;
  const myFoo: Foo = snapshot.data();
}

);
```

And the editor complains:

```
Type 'DocumentData' is not assignable to type 'Foo'
```

What's the best way to specify that the snapshot.data() will be of type Foo, that way I can get autocomplete working well.

Can I just go `<Foo> snapshot.data();` ?

Comment: `const myFoo: Foo = snapshot.data() as Foo;`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typescript interface conformance with firestore queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51606198/typescript-interface-conformance-with-firestore-queries)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

```
const myFoo = snapshot.data() as Foo;
```

Or

```
const myFoo = <Foo> snapshot.data();
```

If the names of the fields of your document don't match the names of the properties of Foo, you might be in for an unpleasant surprise.